# Print the executed PHP code (Path of code taken)

Tags: php, xdebug

I have a script with alot of nested includes and functions calling each other from lots of if conditions. Basically, its a coding nightmare.

Is there any way i can "PRINT" the PHP code executed ? I mean, print the actual flow of the code and the path taken by the script from start to end ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP can't do this out of the box.  You'd need to install [the xDebug extension](http://www.xdebug.org/) on your PHP development machine. Once installed, you could use [the code coverage function](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage) to determine which lines have executed.

Lacking that, I'd create a simple debug function to include at the top of your code

```
public function myDebugString($string)
{
    file_put_contents('/tmp/debug.log',"$string\n",FILE_APPEND);
    return;
}
```

and then add calls to this throughout you code

```
myDebugString('Called at ' . __LINE__);
```

And then tail the log file created. Removing the debug statements is a simple find/replace operation for your editor once you're done.

Many frameworks have debugging objects that do way more than this built it, but if you're dealing with stand alone code something simple like this should be enough to get you by.

Comment: Yes it can! debug_backtrace() will do what he wants. Xdebug will give him the possibility of generating a cachegrind file.

Comment: the debug_backtrace functions are useful, but they only return you a callstack at any given time.  It sounds like the OP wants a line-by-line trace of his code, which means a more advanced tool like xdebug.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) or [debug_print_backtrace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php).

Additionally, I recommend using **[Xdebug](http://xdebug.org)**. It prints a very useful **stack trace** on exceptions (you can configure it to print out every method parameter and every local variable (`xdebug.collect_params=4` and `xdebug.show_local_vars=on` configuration parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [code coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348850/code-coverage-tools-for-php) tools. This allows you to identify those functions and lines of code that are actually executed when a script runs