# php code coverage and selenium setup

Tags: php, selenium

I have the same question as

[PHP code coverage and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383016/php-code-coverage-and-selenium#)

but I am hoping someone could help me with more detail of the setup.

I have found php.ini file for auto-prepend script, but I am wondering 
how the xdebug_start_code_coverage()  and xdebug_get_code_coverage() works and how to set it up...

Thanks.